# Howe to get max count of table rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have few data like this[image]

I want to get the max count,how to get this using a SQL Server query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation :

```
select top (1) department, count(*)
from t
group by department
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you could have duplicates -- and you want all of them -- then use `top (1) with ties`:

```
select top (1) with ties department, count(*)
from t
group by department
order by count(*) desc;
```